# Apache SetEnvIf failing to match Request_Uri

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

Simple condition, which never match and set variable:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/path/to/something*" access_granted
```

Checking URI by using PHP is giving correct string, however variable is never set.

```
echo getenv('Request_URI'); --> /path/to/something
echo getenv('access_granted'); --> <<empty>>
```

Simple as that, but still and always failing to match.

**Update:** interesting point is, that I can achieve access_granted=1 by string:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/path/*" access_granted
```

`/path` is also RewriteBase - maybe it's connected somehow, I don't know

Answer (score 5):

The issue you are facing is maybe caused by mod_rewrite as explained  [under](http://ahrrikis.blogspot.de/2015/08/setenvif-requesturi-not-working-due-to.html). Rewrite rules are applied before applying setenv, so that the rewritten request uri is passed to it. Try to set the env variable on rewrite.

Comment: This correctly explains the problem and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I am having this problem on a server without mod_rewrite enabled, so it may not be the only explanation for this problem

Answer (score 3):

Second argument to `SetEnvIf` is supposed to be regexp, so it should read as:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/path/to/something.* access_granted
```

your second  attempt:

```
 SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/path/*" access_granted
```

works because indeed you have 0 or more "/" symbols following `/path`

In other words - you've attempted to use shell globs where regexp is expected.

Comment: Good point, I did not realized, that dot is missing there. However, now even 2nd attempt does not work, until I simplify regex to `SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/.*$ NotificationUri` . Seems, like there is something else in the URI, as appears to be. Maybe mod_rewrite is screwing things up ?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old topic, but I came across it on my current research, maybe others will have related issues...

For me the following code worked fine and the expression was matched after rewrites!

URL: www.example.de/lockthissite/

.htaccess code:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/lockthissite/$ SECURED=yes

AuthType Basic 
AuthName "restricted access" 
AuthUserFile /path/to/my/.htpasswd 
Require valid-user 
Satisfy any 
Order allow,deny 
Allow from all
Deny from env=SECURED
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution.  `Request_URI` is not the name of the environment variable, you're setting a variable called `access_granted`.

Comment: OK, seems, that I wrote my question wrong. Sure, I'm checking access_granted also, but it's always unset, therefore I didn't mention it in code.
Second line of code is only showing, that Request_URI is exactly same as I whrote to condition.

Comment: It isn't exactly unset, it is empty because you don't assign any value to the variable... That would require something like: `SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/path/to/something*" access_granted=<value>`

Comment: I'm affrraid, =XY is not mandatory :) When is not set, apache is assigning 1 by default, according to docs..
But I tried it also, no change unfortunately. Regex simply does not match in my opinion. There must be something changing the URI, maybe mod_rewrite or I don't know.

Comment: Maybe `PassEnv access_granted`?

Comment: Not sure if I've got your point :) access_granted is not an shell variable, so does it help anyway ?
I've tried that anyway - no change unfortunately